# Days from dates in qlikview expression

Tags: expression, formula, qlikview

I am trying to get days from given data like this:

[image]

In this  data suppose ID B `start date` is `4/10/2019` and `end date` is `10/25/2019`. Here there is 7 months: April to October, so for the first month `start date` is `4/10/2019` and  `end date` is `4/30/2019` so this means he only avail 10 days from this month and remaining days is 21.. same for here `end date` is `10/25/2019` so if we look calendar end date `10/31/2019` we only avail 6 days so in data I want to get above data which is mentioned in image .. where as I am trying this formula in qlikview:

```
=sum(
  If(
    MonthName(CalendarMonthEnd) = MonthName([End Date]),
    ([End Date]-CalendarMonthStart+1),
    (RangeMin([End Date],CalendarMonthEnd)-RangeMax([Start Date],CalendarMonthStart))
  )
)
```

and through this formula I get this data which is remaining days where i want to get days which is availed...

[image]

this is link of folder please download and check ..

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v48373io1bv9qqj/file_qlik.rar?dl=0

in this folder the excel file "output.. " in this excel file the first table output which i need

Comment: First link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Just add another if

```
=Sum(
    If(CalendarMonthStart >= [Start Date] and CalendarMonthEnd <= [End Date],
             CalendarMonthEnd-CalendarMonthStart,
        If([Start Date]>CalendarMonthStart,
            [Start Date]-CalendarMonthStart+1,
            CalendarMonthEnd-[End Date])
    )
 )
)
```

Comment: this shows me wrong values... this is link of folder please download and check .. https://www.dropbox.com/s/v48373io1bv9qqj/file_qlik.rar?dl=0 .. in this folder the excel file "output.. " in this excel file the first table output which i need

Comment: hello @Hubert Dudek any solution please

Comment: I will try to look to it tomorrow

Comment: I updated answer. In future you can learn how to create master calendar so it will be easier witch such a things.

Comment: have my answer helped?

Comment: at the second last record end date 31/Dec/2017 and calendar month end i get 1 day where it should be 31 days because he availed whole month